# Are there cases where either an Acquire or Release barrier occurs by itself without the other matching barrier?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, linux-kernel, atomic

Is it necessary to always pair the Acquire and Release barriers? Are there any genuine cases where one may occur without the corresponding pair (including full memory barriers which satisfy both)? I know that the C++11 memory model states that such unpaired programs are not Data Race Free, but is this always the case?

For example, the [linux kernel's documentation on memory barriers states](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt):

> An ACQUIRE operation should **almost always** be paired with a RELEASE
>        operation.

Why does it say "almost always" and not "always"?

Comment: What that means is that you should usually make the pairing, and not try to find the edge case.  If you need the edge case, it will become apparent when you try to write the code requiring it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Not that I don't appreciate your comment, but a specific code example where such an edge case would be legal or  even be the most common case, would be helpful in understanding the behaviour of the barrier and help in reaffirming my intuition :)

Answer (score 1):

A typical edge case is when you have **2** `ACQUIRE`'s that match a single `RELEASE`. Not strictly paired, but this may simplify some code flow where otherwise you'd need to keep flags saying an `ACQUIRE` is pending.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand [dispatch_once source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-339.90.1/src/once.c) omits read-acquire barrier in performance purposes.

You can find more information in this [blog](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-06-06-secrets-of-dispatch_once.html)